# Using a JOIN involving a View and a Table returns more records than expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

Consider these three tables:

**Content:**

```
Id(pk), Name, and ContentTypeId(fk from ContentType)
```

**ContentTypeId:**

*This table will have values like*

> 1 Text
>
> 2 Number
>
> ...

```
Id(pk), Value
```

**ContentUpdates:**

```
Id(fk from Content), Status, UpdateDate
```

To get data from all three for a report there is a View like so:

```
select C.Id, C.Name, CT.Value, CU.UpdateDate
from ContentUpdates CU 
join Content C 
  On CU.Id = C.Id
join ContentType CT 
  On C.ContentTypeId = CT.Id;
```

Currently this particular View gives me 800 records.

I had a similar requirement where in I needed all those columns plus a filter based on the Status column in ContentUpdates table

I thought of using this View joining the 'ContentUpdates' table on the ID.

So I might want to get all the Content that has a Status of 5, for example.
Currently there are only 2 records with that Status, however using a JOIN on the View the result set has way more records than that.

What am I doing wrong?

Can the View be actually used or am I better off with this:

```
SELECT C.Id, C.Name, CT.Value, CU.UpdateDate
FROM ContentUpdates CU 
JOIN Content C 
  On CS.Id = C.Id
JOIN ContentType CT 
  On C.ContentTypeId = CT.Id
WHERE CU.Status = 5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a view, but you need to expose any of the fields you want to query by or display:

```
CREATE VIEW content_view
AS 
SELECT C.Id, C.Name, CT.Value, CU.UpdateDate, CU.Status
FROM ContentUpdates CU 
INNER JOIN Content C On CS.Id = C.Id
INNER JOIN ContentType CT On C.ContentTypeId = CT.Id;
```

then:

```
SELECT * FROM content_view WHERE Status = 5;
```